# Make the SQL Database manage CRUD operations

Tags: trigger, transaction, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to have a client app send a transaction of INSERTs to a table. Then have the table triggered somehow to run through the inserts and either INSERT the row or UPDATE an existing row?

If it is possible how would this be done on Azure Sql?

Comment: Sure, you can use an instead of trigger

Comment: You can also use MERGE to accomplish that. It's designed to update or insert based on a join.